Problems when attempting to make a irregular design hollow with solidify modifier
I'm trying to hollow out an irregular object I made in Blender, using mostly sculpting and other techniques. The idea is to manufacture this with some injection molding technique, so the engineers want a clean version they can use to create the mold. When I use the Solidify Modifier, you can see in the picture that it is creating lots of weird geometries and not producing a hollow version that would be adequate for production. Anyone have any ideas? Ideal scenario is my shape hollowed out with even thickness. Picture attached is an example version of my problem. You can see what the Solidify Modifier is doing internally on the left hand side. Right hand side is example without any modifier.


Did You apply the scale in Object Mode?

Hello and welcome. Could you provide the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com
